# Header pushing the containing div down from top?

Tags: html, css, margins

I'm new to stackoverflow and web development altogether. Trying to learn without any help. I'm trying to create a C.V of sorts as part of honing my skills. Here's what happened.

The first div under my containing div is a div with id `header`. I've fixed my containing div to top with `margin: 0 auto;` It works fine with no text in my nested `div` (header) but as soon as I write something in (header) `div` it pushes the header `div` down and since header is the first `div`/element in the containing `div`, it pushes that down as well.

Here's my **HTML**:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 12px/18px'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #44accf;
}
/* Positioning Rules */

#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  background: #b7d84b;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Did We?</title>
  <link href="didwe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1> Mansoor Zia </h1> 

  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
</body>

</html>
```

I'm unable to attach the image here since I'm well the newest member.

Comment: Look into margin collapsing, find some information [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `h1{margin:0}` to your css and that fixes your problem. Just so you know, unless defined otherwise all text elements have margin which screws around with positioning and sizing :)

Comment: It worked. A follow up question though, the text margin in #header is within that div, so shouldn't it be screwing with the text position within that div. That's padding's job, I know. So, the text margin does effect the margin of whole div, in all cases?

Comment: @MansoorZia Please see my answer for information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser sets its value default styles for a variety of HTML-elements. With CSS Reset, we can neutralize this difference to ensure cross-browser style.

use http://cssreset.com

```css
/* v2.0 | 20110126
  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
  License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    font: normal 12px/18px'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #44accf;
}
/* Positioning Rules */
 #container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    background: #b7d84b;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ddd;
    line-height: 50px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
         <h1> Mansoor Zia </h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution http://jsfiddle.net/hovru6qh/

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You need to reset all padding and margin

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the opening

```html
<body>
```

-tag, could be that.

Also, instead of using

```css
margin: 0 auto;
```

to get it to stick to the top of the page, try using

```css
top: *margin to top*(0 = sticks to top without margin)
```

Comment: I also had to center the containing div on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Margins inside of block elements will - by default - overflow bi-directionally vertically when the element with the margin is set to `display` in `inline-block` or `inline` (`h1` elements display in `inline` by default).

To fix this without changing the `margin` of your H1 text, but fixing the header to not be effected by it (as it shouldn't), add `overflow: auto` to the CSS of your header.

A Fiddle is here for you:

[Bi-directional margin overflow fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kanaikimi/dmhh1hLd/)

Good luck!

Comment: overflow does put it right on the top but adds a scroll bar in my header which isn't ideal.

Comment: You could use `overflow: hidden` to acheive the same thing but without scrollbars. The issue with this though as it will clip content as you have a fixed height. Possibly use `overflow: auto` with no fixed height or maybe `minimum-height` as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers seem a bit misleading so I decided to create this one to outline the problem for you.

The problem is called **margin collapsing**, you can read about it a little [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

A fix for this would be to remove the default margin on the `<h1>` tag, see an example below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 12px/18px'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #44accf;
}
#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  background: #b7d84b;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  line-height: 50px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0; /* Added this */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1> Mansoor Zia </h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```